# How to arrange web application docker containers in production stage

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, docker, containers

I'm approaching to the Linux Container world by looking at one of maybe the most famous and used containers manager that is Docker. I have quite clear the advantages of using Docker at the development stage. Fast and easy creation of image including any sort of application (database, server, etc...) but I haven't clear yet the advantages in production. I mean let's assume two have three different instance running on AWS running docker. In one instance I decide to run a web server container (nodejs), in the second one a database container (mongodb) and the last one a cache container (redis). All these ones running in their own container running in one separate instance. The deployment is fast and easy but how many others containers can I run in the other instance and which one? I don't mean to say the maximum number of containers. I know that it depends from the memory. I mean which other kinds of containers could have the reason to running in one of these three instance? For example I would add in the future nginx. In which of this one should I place it? Should I take another aws ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it will depend on your resource requirements which containers you place together. However, AWS offers container service (in Preview) that allows running docker containers and comes with a scheduler that can decide where to put things. Maybe this would be an option?

From http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/details/:

> Amazon EC2 Container Service comes with a default scheduler that
>   schedules containers to help find the optimal instance placement based
>   on your resource needs (e.g., CPU or RAM) and availability
>   requirements. The EC2 Container Service APIs also provide you with
>   complete cluster state information, allowing you to write your own
>   scheduler or integrate existing 3rd party schedulers if you choose.